# Как передать json во vue.js?

Tags: vue.js

Есть следующий код:

```
var categoriesJson = [
    {
        "name": "Цветы",
        "link": "flowers",
        "id": 1,
        "childrens": [
            {
                "name":"пионы",
                "link":"piony"
            },
            {
                "name":"розы",
                "link":"roses"
            }
        ]
    }
];

new Vue({
    el: '#productapp',
    data: {
        name: '',
        link: '',
        tags: '',
        categories: JSON.parse(categoriesJson) 
    },
    methods: {
        setProductName(name) {
            this.link = window.slugify(name);
        }
    }
});
```

`var categoriesJson` берется из бэкэнда при рендере страницы, т.е. его рендерит php. Каким образом я могу передать `categories` в объект `Vue`?

UPD: еще вопрос: почему `JSON.parse(categoriesJson)` выдает `unexpected token`?

Comment: повеситься на .created() / .mounted() и получать аякс-запросом

Comment: @etki если нет возможности сделать так, что делать?

Comment: почему нет возможности?

Comment: @etki бэкэнд уже разработан, данные во view из бэка идут в таком формате сейчас

Comment: Тогда вам просто надо убрать JSON.parse и передавать в чистом виде.